# Strange behaviour of itertools.groupby in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Converting `itertools.groupby` objects to lists seems to leed to strange behaviour. I don't understand why `a = groupby(lst, is_divisible_by_four)` produces different results to `a = list(groupby(lst, is_divisible_by_four))`.

```
>>> def is_divisible_by_four(x):
        return x % 4 == 0

>>> lst = list(range(10))
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a = groupby(lst, is_divisible_by_four)
>>> [list(i[1]) for i in a]
[[0], [1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7], [8], [9]]
>>> a = list(groupby(lst, is_divisible_by_four))
>>> a
[(True, <itertools._grouper object at 0x00FA9C10>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0x00FA9DF0>), (True, <itertools._grouper object at 0x00FA9C70>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0x010092F0>), (True, <itertools._grouper object at 0x01009390>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0x01009290>)]
>>> [list(i[1]) for i in a]
[[], [9], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: This is documented right there in the manual.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that this is a duplicate. Is there any explanation for the result of `[[], [9], [], [], [], []]`? I would understand if the `[9]` (the last result) was at the end, but it isn't. But `groupby` objects seem ordered, so this seems strange.

Comment: `9` is the last value in the list, left there for the last group, and the second group is the first group it could be part of according to the grouping key.

Comment: so by the time you called `list()` on the `groupby()` object, the last value produced for the `key` is `True`, and the first group being iterated will find only `9` still left in the iterator. It produces `False` for the key function, so the first group is empty. Then `list()` on the second group still finds `9` in the iterator. The `key` function returns `True`, which is the same as the group key, so `9` is returned and the iterable is empty. All subsequent groups are left empty.